# Convert hierarchical text list to discrete lists

Tags: xslt, awk, hierarchical-data

What's a smart way to extract one level of depth from a large hierarchy? Imagine the following tab-delimited hierarchical text list:

```
plants
   fruits
      apples
      bananas
      cherries
   trees
      oaks
      maples
   vegetables
      onions
      peppers
```

The goal is to output just the sublists with one-level of depth:

```
plants
   fruits
   trees
   vegetables

fruits
   apples
   bananas
   cherries

trees
   oaks
   maples

vegetables
   onions
   peppers
```

Should work on a mac, and on larger/deeper files. For example, here's a larger file:

```
life
    animals
        mammals
            dogs
            cats
            rabbits
        fish
            salmon
        birds
    plants
        fruits
            apples
            bananas
            cherries
            mangoes
        trees
            oaks
            maples
            birch
            pine
        vegetables
            onions
            peppers
```

And this would be the output from the larger input:

```
life
    animals
    plants

animals
    mammals
    fish
    birds

mammals
    dogs
    cats
    rabbits

fish
    salmon

plants
    fruits
    trees
    vegetables

fruits
    apples
    bananas
    cherries
    mangoes

trees
    oaks
    maples
    birch
    pine

vegetables
    onions
    peppers
```

Comment: I added a larger example, so sorry it's a larger question now.

Comment: Does the output order matter or could, say, the block consisting of trees and it's children come between the animals block and the mammals block?

Comment: Output order does not matter. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have tagged the question as XSLT, I post an XSLT 3.0 solution that should work with the commercial versions of Saxon 9.6 (as for instance available with oXygen) or Saxon 9.7 or with Exselt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math mf"
    version="3.0">

<xsl:param name="text-uri" as="xs:string" select="'test2016030301.txt'"/>

<xsl:param name="indent" as="xs:string" select="'&#9;'"/>

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:function name="mf:group" as="element(item)*">
    <xsl:param name="lines" as="xs:string*"/>
    <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$lines" group-starting-with=".[. instance of xs:string and matches(., '^' || string-join((1 to $level)!$indent) || '\w')]">
        <item data="{normalize-space()}">
            <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group()[position() gt 1], $level + 1)"/>
        </item>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template name="main" match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="mf:group(unparsed-text-lines($text-uri), 0)"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:value-of select="@data, */($indent || @data)" separator="&#10;"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="item[item]"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Call the XSLT with `it:main` and the URI of the text file as a parameter `text-uri`.